# Where is the python log location for freeradius python module?

Tags: python, freeradius

My `freeradius` has a python module for authentication. And I want to find the location of `print str(e)` of the following code.

```
try:
    cursor.execute(query)
except Exception, e:
    print str(e)
    conn.rollback()
```

It doesn't print to `freeradius` console. The operating system is Ubuntu and python version is 2.7. Appreciate any help

Comment: Without context, it is not easy to tell where the print() output goes. Can you run this code in debug mode? If yes, set a halt point at the print statement in question and then read the current state of the sys.stdout object.

Comment: Unable to run it in debug mode as it is in the production environment.

Comment: Then you need more context. Maybe trying to find where sys.stdout is manipulated could be a start.